# Is there any way to obtains CMOS Status?

Tags: android, samsung-mobile, battery, samsung-mobile-sdk, android-powermanager

I would like to know,
1) Is there any way to access status of CMOS Battery in android(specially in Sumsung)?

Or

2) Is there any API or some classes/Methods which can access CMOS battery?

I didn't find anything on this subject...

Thank you guys !

Comment: Are you sure that there is a CMOS Battery in common android devices?

AFAIK, what you are reffering you is used in e.g. x86 PCs to hold BIOS Settings used to control the boot process.

Comment: http://i1116.photobucket.com/albums/k562/weinerwad3000/SANY0318.jpg, http://www.tomshardware.com/answers/id-1678971/tablet-smartphones-cmos-pram-batteries-real-time-clocks.html http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1471571

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That may be an RTC (real-time clock) battery... I personally doubt it's a BIOS-type battery since Android devices normally write data to NVRAM (EEPROM or flash). It's unlikely there is a specific battery level monitor circuit present, let alone one that you could read the state of: the cheap and easy way to detect a dead CMOS battery on a PC is if the CMOS settings are corrupt on boot-up (checking guard bits, checksums, or looking for plainly impossible settings), thus triggering a warning to the user to the effect of a bad checksum or possible bad battery.

It's typically not worth the board real estate and part cost to add a monitor for something that's low-priority or where software detection and defaults are acceptable (a server that depends on a battery for maintaining more critical config info in CMOS is another matter and thus is more likely to have such circuitry and possibly APIs as well... a mis-set clock on an Android device will get corrected as soon as it talks to the network).

All that said, it's not quite clear why they bothered to put a battery in that device at all... but if it's for something more complex than the clock it's also probably very specific to the device and its firmware (not easily generalized nor accessible from Android directly).